# Flex/Bison: Comma-separated linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, bison, flex-lexer

I have the following grammar for a comma-separated list with at least one item:

```
column_expression_list:
    column_expression {
        $$ = LinkedList_New();
        LinkedListItem *item = LinkedListItem_New($1);
        LinkedList_add($$, item);
    }
    |
    column_expression_list T_COMMA column_expression {
        LinkedListItem *item = LinkedListItem_New($3);
        LinkedList_add($1, item);
    }
;
```

Does `column_expression_list` always ultimately breaks down to a `column_expression` and therefore each linked list item will always be added safely to the linked list?

If not, whats the correct grammar to accomplish this?

Comment: That looks okay by me. Although I would personally have used right-recursion on the list (`column_expression T_COMMA column_expression_list`) instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg your suggestion causes it to crash. Is there a performance benefit in doing it that way?

Comment: Well you have to switch `$1` and `$3` of course. The only difference otherwise is where the `column_expression` node will be added, head or tail.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is fine: there is no other means to build `column_expression_list` than the first of your two rules, since the second requires one to be already "recognized".  Of course if you have other rules elsewhere about `column_expression_list`, things might be different.

You are right to prefer left-recursion over right-recursion in the case of LR parsers: they save space, and, in the case of interactive parsers, behave the way you want.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Recursion.html for instance.